# Bootstrap Fonts look Like Italic and Bold

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, webfonts

Hi this might be out of scripting scope but I really need your helps to figure it out why bootstrap 3 Fonts looks like Bolded and Italic ONLY on my laptop.

[image]

Here is what it looks like. I almost have no problem with other fonts except of Bootstrap and also input boxes in Stackowerflow pages like

[image]

Comment: Try to reinstall Helvetica Neue, Helvetica fonts on your machine

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Here two cases are possible:

1. You have included fonts on your web server locally and you have named them wrong. In that case Change your web fonts.
2. Second font with the same is not installed in your system properly. So reinstall the fonts again.